# How do I get information from a Parse.com pointer object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parse-platform

I created a class:

```
class MyClass
  ...
  def all_photos_this_month(m)
    #Set time interval to get photos - Get only photos of the month.
    month = m
    next_month = month + 1
    @get_month_photos = Parse::Query.new("Photo").tap do |q|
      q.greater_than("createdAt", Parse::Date.new("#{Time.now.year}-#{month}-01T00:00:00-03:00"))
      q.less_than("createdAt", Parse::Date.new("#{Time.now.year}-#{next_month}-01T00:00:00-03:00"))
    end.get
    return @get_month_photos
  end
  def get_user_photos_of_month(userid, month)     
    user_photos_this_month = all_photos_this_month(month).find_all {|user| user["user"]["objectId"] == userid }
    return user_photos_this_month
  end
end
```

with which I''m using to get some photos from the Parse.com API. The message I send to get a users photo for a month is:

```
.get_user_photos_of_month(userid, month)
```

However I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method []' for #<Parse::Pointer:0x007fc3e3122dd0> from
/Users/abarro/projects/parse/client.rb:142:in block in get_user_photos_of_month' from
/Users/abarro/projects/parse/client.rb:142:in each' from
/Users/abarro/projects/parse/client.rb:142:in find_all' from
/Users/abarro/projects/parse/client.rb:142:in get_user_photos_of_month' from
(irb):15 from
/Users/abarro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/irb:11:in <main>'
```

Where does this error come from?

Comment: The error should be providing you with a line number as well. What line of your method is causing the error?

Comment: Hi @kevinthompson this is the error, I do not know how to read witch line it is pointing, can you help me out?

`NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for #<Parse::Pointer:0x007fc3e3122dd0>
 from /Users/abarro/projects/parse/client.rb:142:in `block in get_user_photos_of_month'
 from /Users/abarro/projects/parse/client.rb:142:in `each'
 from /Users/abarro/projects/parse/client.rb:142:in `find_all'
 from /Users/abarro/projects/parse/client.rb:142:in `get_user_photos_of_month'
 from (irb):15
 from /Users/abarro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'`

Comment: `client.rb:142` is the relevant bit. That says the error is on line 142 of the `client.rb` file. It looks like the error is due to the type of object you're returning from `all_photos_this_month`. I'm not too familiar with Parse, but I think you may be returning the query pointer instead of the query results.

Comment: Ok that is interesting. I will try some new stuff and get back here If I fand any answer. Thanks for pointing me a path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part was wrong:

```
all_photos_this_month(month).find_all {|user| user["user"]["objectId"] == userid }
```

It got me the error shown above.

For me to get the **user["user"]["objectId"]** first I needed to transform the pointer into a hash.

Like this:

```
user["user"].pointer.to_h["objectId"]
```